# Using Klaxon for JSON with Arrow for Option in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt, klaxon

Koltin newbie here. If I have a library with (Kotlin) Borrowers and Books and a `Book` is checked out when it has a `Borrower` (using Arrow's `Option` datatype):

```
data class Borrower(val name: Name, val maxBooks: MaxBooks)
data class Book(val title: Title, val author: Author, val maybeBorrower: Option<Borrower> = None)
```

How do I encode and decode between a tiny library:

```
val br1 = Borrower("Borrower1", 1)
val bk1 = Book("Title1", "Author1", Some(br1))
val bk2 = Book("Title2", "Author2", None)
```

And it's JSON representation:

```
val jsonStringBooks = """[{"title":"Title1","author":"Author1","borrower":{"name":"Borrower1","maxBooks":1}},{"title":"Title2","author":"Author2","borrower":null}]"""
```

Using Klaxon?

The representation of an `Option` (or `Either`?) through Klaxon is throwing me off. I believe Scala's spray-json handles these datatypes.

Thank you.

Comment: how would you expect to be represented? Also have you checked [Helios]?(https://github.com/47deg/helios)

Comment: I checked Helios before posting the question. I saw no discussion or example of encoding/decoding an `Option` datatype.